# Is recursion only possible in Function Expression ? Tried it in simple codes using Function declaration and it still works, Am I missing something

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have heard that recursion is only possible in function expressions, but i have tried it in function declarations and it worked fine. I can show this, by writing a simple code to calculate sum of first n natural numbers.

**1. Using Function Expression :**

```js
var addNum = function sumTest(n)
{
  if (n === 1)
    return 1;
  return (n + sumtest(n - 1));
};

console.log(addNum(100)); // output will be 5050 in console.
```

**2. Using Function Declaration :**

```js
function sumTest(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (n + sumTest(n - 1));
  }
}

console.log(sumTest(100)); // output 5050 in console.
```

so is recursion successful in function declaration too ??

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You can indeed use recursion with both a function declaration and a function expression, as your code shows, whoever said that is wrong

Comment: Why do you think it would make a difference? Recursion is just calling the same function, it doesn't matter how it's defined.

Comment: As long as the name of the function is in the scope of the function body, you can recurse.